# I need to parse a number by 4 digits in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

I just started out using antlr4 I just want to write a grammar that can parse through a number series but only select 4 digits at a time

for example, I have a number 1234567891234567
then I want it to parse first 4 digits into 1 token the next into another and the next into another so that I get 4 different 4 digit tokens.

```
token1 = 1234,
token2 = 5678,
token3 = 9123,
token4 = 4567,
```

can anyone help me write a grammar for this

```
   grammar TEST;

    /*
     * Parser Rules
     */

    test             :   (example+ EOF);
    example          :   digit COMMA digit2 NEWLINE;
    digit            :   SINGLE+;
    digit2           :   QUADRUPLE+;


    /*
     * Lexer Rules
     */

     SINGLE:
        INT 
   ;

    QUADRUPLE:
       INT INT INT INT
   ;

   fragment INT:
       [0-9]
    ;
   NEWLINE    : ('\r'? '\n' | '\r')+ ;
   COMMA      : ',';
```

[image]

here's the grammar I have written what I need it to print single digits as tokens 1st and then after a comma I need the numbers to be printed as 4digits in tokens please check the attached image and help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The respective lexer rule would look like this:

```
QUADRUPLE:
    INT INT INT INT
;

fragment INT:
    [0-9]
;
```

So the key to this problem is to renounce using one of ANTLR's "repeating-operators" (`*`, `+`) and simply write the repetition by hand so that it matches exactly the desired count.

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the solution you were looking for, you can mark my answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: I did but it says it has recorded my feedback but it needs 15 reputation to show it to public sorry for that as soon as I get my reputation up I'll again upvote the answer... :)

Comment: How can i do the same for accepting single digit at a time and take the input and print it as a date for example let the input be 00000 I want it to be printed as token1=0, token2=0, token3=0, token4=0, token5=0 and for the date one  input is 161117 and parse it as token=16-11-17 can you please help me with this.

Comment: Interesting... That must be new ^^ What you are asking is not possible. It would require context-sensitive lexing (The lexer needed to know whether the given numbers correspond to a date or not). Maybe if you open a new question in which you describe what you want and why (provide input and the expected output) you could get printed to an alternative way

Comment: Okay then what about the above grammar I posted, it's not taking the input as I want I want it to consider numbers before COMMA as single digits and after COMMA as 4 digits but it's not considering the grammar to take single digits in the start, any idea of how to do it

Comment: Yep... Do it in the parser. Create a lexer rule like the INT fragment in my example (just without the fragment keyword) and the create a parser rule that matches either one INT or four INT in a row. In your top parser rule you match the first parser rule until a COMMA is detected and afterwards match the second parser rule until the input ends

Comment: `grammar Te;`

`test : (example+ EOF);`
`example: digit COMMA digit2 NEWLINE;`
`digit: (INT)+? ;`
`digit2: (INT INT INT INT)*?;`

LEXER
`INT :[0-9];`
`COMMA: ',';`
`NEWLINE : ('\r'? '\n' | '\r')+ ;  `

this is what I have written but still, it's considering the digits after COMMA as single digits

Comment: Open a new question and post the grammar and all relevant information there properly. I don't want to do this via the comment section.

Comment: here's the link to the new thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349729/antlr4-grammar-for-splitting-the-number